# Flashing MCU using JTAG ICE 3 / Avrdude / Beagle Bone Black

Tags: atmel, jtag, avrdude, beaglebone-black, debian

I am in need of flashing ATmega1284P using Beagle Bone Black. I have JTAG ICE 3 connected via USB cable to Beagle Bone Black with Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy). I have compiled version of Avrdude 6.1 which should support jtag ice 3 programmer. The problem is, when I run avrdude, it ends up with error message:

`usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"`

I guess avrdude can't recognize connected jtagice, but I can see it using `lsusb` command with result:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 03eb:2140 Atmel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: [After a firmware upgrade of my JTAGICE3 (1.25 -> 3.23) my JTAGIC3 had
become totally unusable: avrdude 6.0.1 failed top open the USB port (...
did not find any device "usb"). Some googling showed that this is a
known problem, and which has been fixed on avrdude-6.1.](http://avr.2057.n7.nabble.com/Support-for-JTAGICE3-on-avrdude-td20962.html)

Comment: Just to clarify how we ended: we used reflashed BBB with different programmer - AVR Dragon, so we avoided the issue. It worked out-of-the-box with Dragon.